# Can MotionDetection in Swift perform 2 different actions?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am detecting when a user shakes his phone. Is it possible to perform 2 independent actions? I mean first do this1, then do this2.

```
override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        // first this needs to be done
        let scene = makeScene()
        animationView.frame.size = scene.size
        animationView.presentScene(scene)

        // then this needs to be done
        let scene2 = makeScene2()
        animationView.frame.size = scene2.size
        animationView.presentScene(scene2)
    }
}
```

When I do that only the second one is executed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with hardcoded delays, try wrapping your animation in a `CATransaction` and run your 2nd step in its completion handler:

```
override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
   if motion == .motionShake {
      CATransaction.begin()

      let scene = makeScene()
      animationView.frame.size = scene.size
      animationView.presentScene(scene)

      CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
         let scene2 = self.makeScene2()
         self.animationView.frame.size = scene2.size
         self.animationView.presentScene(scene2)
      }


      CATransaction.commit()
   }
}
```

Comment: error: Type 'CATransaction' has no member 'set CompletionHandler'
What should I do?

Comment: sorry, it's `setCompletionBlock`, updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem by adding a delay between the actions.

```
override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {

        let scene = makeScene()
        animationView.frame.size = scene.size
        animationView.presentScene(scene)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(4), execute: {

            let scene2 = self.makeScene2()
            self.animationView.frame.size = scene2.size
            self.animationView.presentScene(scene2)

        })


    }
    }
    }
```